# How the OS knows a page is dirty in mapped memory?

Tags: linux, windows, memory-mapped-files

I mean when data is updated directly in memory, without using write().

In linux I thought all the data specified in a msync call was flushed.

But in Windows the doc of FlushViewOfFile says "writing of dirty pages", so somehow the OS knows what pages have been updated.

How does that work ? Do we have to use WriteFile to update mapped memory ?
If we use write() in linux does msync only syncs dirty pages ?

Comment: Basically the OS uses hardware support. For example, a page can initially be marked read only. Then on first write a page fault will be generated which the OS handles. At that point the page can be marked dirty and made writable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On most (perhaps all) modern-day computers running either Linux or Windows, the CPU keeps track of dirty pages on the operating system's behalf.  This information is stored in the [page table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_table).

(See, for example, section 4.8 of the [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures
Software Developer’s Manual, Volume 3A](http://www.intel.com/Assets/en_US/PDF/manual/253668.pdf) and section 5.4.2 in the [AMD64 Architecture Programmer's Manual, Volume 2](http://support.amd.com/TechDocs/24593.pdf).)

If that functionality isn't available on a particular CPU, an operating system could instead use page faults to detect the first write to a page, as described in datenwolf's answer.

Answer (score 3):

When flushing pages (i.e. cleaning them up) the OS internally removes the "writeable" flag. After that, when a program attempts to write to a memory location in such a page, the kernel's page fault handler is invoked. The page fault handler then sets the page access permissions to allow the actual write and marks the page dirty, then returns control to the program to let it perform the actual write.

Comment: Unless I'm reading [Intel's documentation](http://www.intel.com/Assets/en_US/PDF/manual/253668.pdf) incorrectly (see section 4.8) there shouldn't be any need to use a fault handler on modern Intel CPUs, the CPU can set the dirty flag directly.  I imagine AMD has a similar mechanism.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Of course specific architectures will implement such optimizations in hardware. However I aimed to answer the answer in general – there's more than just x86(_64) – and so broad that it can be understood as a pure software operation.

Comment: So you were only providing an example of one way it could be done?  (Your answer reads to me as though it is describing how it *is* done.)

Comment: I change the answer to the one of Harry, Daten's one is good but details about processor support is very relevant. Mention of Intel documentation is useful too.